# Ошибка записи в файл

Tags: php, файлы, запись

Почему не записывается в файл?

```
<?php 
$file = fopen("somefile.txt", r, use_include_path);
$newfile = fopen("somenewfile.txt", "a+", use_include_path);

while (!feof($file)) {
    $content = fgets($file);

    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($content); $i++) { 
        $symbol = substr($content, 0+$i, 1);

            fwrite($newfile, $symbol ." ");             
    }
}
fclose($file);
fclose($newfile);

?>
```

Comment: А из `somefile.txt` данные читаются? Вы уверены, что `$file` не пустое? И, само собой, права записи есть в эту папку?

Comment: До этого делал подобную задачку, все нормально записывалось, чтение в этой программе работает, somefile.txt - не пустой

Comment: все-таки, кажется, больше на проблему доступа... Все же попробуйте поставить `if (!is_writable("somenewfile.txt")) die('not writable');` Что получится?

Comment: Все по прежнему, если я конечно все правильно сделал ( поставил данную конструкцию после объявления $newfile)

Comment: Ну хорошо, а если `fwrite($newfile, "something"); ` поставить перед `while` - оно будет в файле?

Comment: увы, его там не появилось...

Comment: как видите, даже простейшую строчку в файл записать не удается. значит все-таки проблема в доступе. проверьте еще раз путь, куда создается файл, существует ли он... есть ли права на запись...

Answer (score 2):

У вас проблема (даже две) в аргументах функции `fopen`.

1) режим `r` в первом использовании функции не в кавычках

```
$file = fopen("somefile.txt", r, use_include_path);
```

а должен

```
$file = fopen("somefile.txt", "r", use_include_path);
```

---

2) `use_include_path` - необязательный параметр, который может быть установлен либо в `1` либо `TRUE`, если вы также хотите провести поиск файла в `include_path`.

тоесть либо так

```
$file = fopen("somefile.txt", "r");
$newfile = fopen("somenewfile.txt", "a+");
```

либо так

```
$file = fopen("somefile.txt", "r", true);
$newfile = fopen("somenewfile.txt", "a+", true);
```

Comment: последний «либо так» – лишний и неаккуратный. Ф-я [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php) ожидает значение типа `Boolean` для третьего параметра и будет приводить к нему. Поэтому единица, да ещё в кавычках, сбивает с толку. Т.к. например, `'0'`, `'false'` (в кавычках) будут иметь тот же эффект, что и `'1'` и `true`.

Comment: благодарю за замечание, подкорректировал ответ